# C# store different child classes and call them at same time

Tags: c#, inheritance

Actually all these classes are defined in the 3rd lib, so I can't change them.

=====================

I'm learning C# and I met a problem.
Suppose I have a parent class and two child classes:

```cs
class ParentClass
{
    ....
};

class ChildA : ParentClass
{
    public string name;
};

class ChildB : ParentClass
{
    public string name;
};
```

Both class ChildA and ChildB have property `name`, but ParentClass doesn't.
Now I need to store ChildA and ChildB in a dictionary, so I write `Dictionary<string, ParentClass>`.

But I can't get name because ParentClass doesn't have this property:

```cs
foreach (ParentClass pc in dict.Values) 
{
    // it works, but too verbose as I may have ChildC, ChildD...
    if (pc is ChildA ca) 
    {
        ca.name
    }
    if (pc is ChildB cb) 
    {
        cb.name
    }

    // how can I get the name property at same time?
}
```

how can I handle this?

Comment: Have you tried adding the name property in the parent and removing it from the child component?

Comment: when the parentclass doesn't know the property and you have no way to change that, there's no other way than downcasting to the appropriate child.class and call the member there.

Comment: You either need to put name on ParentClass, create an abstract base class and put name on it, create an interface as suggested by Marc Gravell

Answer (score 4):

The short version is "no". There are things that you *could* do if you have access to the types - for example, you could implement a common interface (`interface IHazName { public string Name {get;} }`) - but you can't do that here since you don't control the types.

A lazy way could be to abuse `dynamic`:

```cs
dynamic hack = pc;
hack.name = "yolo";
```

but... please don't! Your `is` approach (or perhaps a `switch` expression) is about as good as you can get. Note that if you need to talk to this member in a lot of places, you *could* move that shared logic to an extension method:

```cs
static class SomeUtilsType {
    public static string GetName(this ParentClass obj) => obj switch {
        ChildA ca => ca.name,
        ChildB cb => cb.name,
        _ => throw new ArgumentException("Unexpected object type", nameof(obj)),
    };
}
...
foreach (ParentClass pc in dict.Values) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(pc.GetName());
}
```

(or a similar set method) - then at least you don't need to repeat yourself.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use reflection on the type to determine if it has a "name" property (or field, as you've shown):

```
public static string GetName(ParentClass parent)
{
    return parent.GetType().GetProperty("name")?.GetValue(parent, null).ToString()
        ?? parent.GetType().GetField("name")?.GetValue(parent).ToString();
}
```

Example usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ParentClass parent = new ParentClass();
    ChildA child = new ChildA { name = "ChildName" };

    Console.WriteLine($"Parent name: {GetName(parent)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Child name: {GetName(child)}");

    Console.Write("\n\nDone. Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Output

```
Parent name:
Child name: ChildName


Done. Press any key to exit...
```